# How can data be stored on an iPhone/iPad based on data volume?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, data-storage, nscoding

I am to make a app which will connect to a remote DB server and fetch images and product descriptions as text. Each product will have 3-5 images. 
How is the best way to store the data I have got from the web server?

1. Using NSUserDefault wont work, because I have to much data.
2. I don't know if using CoreData is really necessary because I have less then 30 days to make the whole app and learning core data might take more time than I have.
3. I found this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

where data is stored locally without using 2. and by using NSCoding. Is this the correct direction? Is there a 4th way?

I would also like to write the app in swift for iOS8.X.X.

Are there any "strict" guidelines when we use this approach or another based on the volume of the data that is being stores? (ex.for low data volumes always use NSUserDefaults, etc.)

Any advice is welcome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinion: CoreData is the way to go. Yes, there is a learning curve - but it's also really pretty awesome. Once you get the hang of it, you will find that it's really a powerful tool and will allow you to tackle more complicated scenarios as you advance. Images can be stored as field data that is stored externally to the db but managed by CoreData.

I don't think data volume is a strong determining factor for choosing any approach - for the scenario you described. Any of those options don't appear to have any real limits.

Having said that, you have not described how many "products" you will have to save, is it 10 or 10,000? If you have to add search capability in the future you may find that CoreData would have been a better choice.

I also think it's perfectly fine to skip CoreData if you really don't have time to learn it, and your deadline is critical.

Comment: Great and simple explanation :). I will have from 10 - 100 products at a maximum of 150. I would then go with the 3.rd solution, load the data from HDD, check for updates from the server and then update the UI and write it to the HDD. You are right, the deadline is critical and I will have to cope with the currently 8 day app approval process  http://appreviewtimes.com/ The next stop is core data for sure :)